# Why this disable form submission does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just need to disable form submission using jQuery. But it does not works.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" id="pro_register_form">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('pro_register_form').submit(function() {
      return false;
    });
});
```

---

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6wr7Lfdu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the jQuery documentation on [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> ... we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler.

And it might be a good practice to stop the normal event handler by calling [`.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on the event (1st argument of the callback).

It appears that the selector passed to [$()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) is not correctly finding the form. Use the id selector (i.e. `#`) to find the form element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pro_register_form').submit(function(event) {
      //accept the event object as the first argument of our callback function

      //and call preventDefault on it to stop the form submission
      event.preventDefault();

      //returning false will also stop the form submission
      return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6wr7Lfdu/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pro_register_form').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: `return false` should be sufficient to cancel the form submission (without needing to call `e.preventDefault()`, per [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: its also good practice to prevent the browser default action on the form submission